# Save game to file

Tags: java, file, serialization

I'm working on a primitive RPG, and this class (supposedly) contains all the necessary data:

```
public class CPU implements Serializable{

private Map<String, Location> locations;
private Map<String, Location> places;
private Map<String, NPC> npcs;
private Game game;
private Player player;
private NPC currentNPC;

public CPU(){

}
```

(I didn't include the methods, but I think those are irrelevant right now...)

The class "Game" also contains the Player and the CPU as variables, but its constructor isn't the one to actually create them (those are created in the main() method, then added to the classes). This method is the one that's supposed to save the CPU class to a file, so that I can read all the data from it later:

```
public void SaveGame(String s){
    String sav = s;
    sav.concat(".dat");
    try {
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(sav));
        oos.writeObject(cpu);
        oos.close();
    } catch(Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And this is the method to load it from the file:

```
public void Load(String s){
    if(s.contains(".dat")){
        try {
            ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(s));
            cpu = (CPU)ois.readObject();
            ois.close();
        } catch(Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

My question is basically: will this work? Am I able to simply serialize the CPU class and save it to a file, then read it back and be able to recover all the data from it (i.e the Player data)?

If I remember correctly, in Java "=" doesn't mean that the object on the right side will be copied, so my other problem is: when the method "Load" finishes, will the "cpu" (variable of the "Game"-class) still contain the CPU that I loaded from the file, and will I be able to read data from it?

Comment: If other classes are serializable it should work e.i. game, player and NPC but why dont you just try?

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: Regarding your last paragraph: Why should the loaded CPU instance magically go away? In Java, you are basically assigning references and as long as you have a reference to some object, it won't be garbage collected.

Comment: Haven't tried it yet because I've been working on it for almost 10 hours, and I'm doing something else for a while... ;)

Answer (score 1):

Actually, it will work only if the original file name that you pass to the `SaveGame()` method contains `".dat"`.

Indeed, the reading method checks that condition, and the `SaveGame()` method (which should be named `saveGame()` to respect the Java naming conventions) doesn't append .dat to the file name as you think. Indeed, Strings are immutable, and the `concat()` method returns a new String, but doesn't modify the String it's called on. The code should be

```
String sav = s.concat(".dat");
```

You should also stop ignoring exceptions like you're doing, and you should always close the streams in a finally block. If you're under Java 7, use the [try-with-resources](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) construct.

Comment: Dammit... String class screwing with me again...

Thanks for the input!

Comment: I'm not ignoring the exceptions, by the way. I just did not include the rest of the "catch" block here. 

But while we're on the subject: would the load method throw a "FileNotFoundException" if the string containing the filename is incorrect? I would like to use that to handle any such errors.

Comment: Yes, as per [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html#FileInputStream%28java.lang.String%29)

Answer (score 0):

If your program has permissions to write files, and all of the field classes (NPC, Game, Player. Location) are serializable as well, then **it will work**.

The `cpu` field of the Game class *will* contain the CPU loaded from the file, *if* no exception is thrown when reading the object.